# Team Foundation cannot retrieve the list of team projects from Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

When I'm trying to connect to tfs I got the following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Team Foundation Server

TF31001: Team Foundation cannot retrieve the list of team projects from Team Foundation Server UGSERVER. The Team Foundation Server returned the following error: Team Foundation services are not available from the server.

Technical information (for administrator):

TF30059: Fatal error while initializing web service.
```

Then, I checked the event viewer and it has the following details:

```
Event Type:    Error
Event Source:    TFS Services
Event Category:    None
Event ID:    3017
Date:        2/2/2010
Time:        9:38:31 AM
User:        N/A
Computer:    UGSERVER
Description:
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 2/2/2010 4:38:31 AM
Machine: UGSERVER
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/738167904/Root/Services-11-129095591107656250
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 408
  Thread Id: 6020
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE

Detailed Message: TF53013: A crash report is being prepared for Microsoft. The following information is included in that report:
System Values
OS Version Information=Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2, v.2845
CLR Version Information=2.0.50727.1433
Machine Name=UGSERVER Processor Count=2
Working Set=52858880
System Directory=C:\WINDOWS\system32
Process Values
ExitCode=0
Interactive=False
Has Shutdown Started=False
Process Environment Variables
Path = C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\
TEMP = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = x86
SystemDrive = C:
windir = C:\WINDOWS
TMP = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
TFSPowerToolDir = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools\
USERPROFILE = C:\Documents and Settings\Default User
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK = NO
COMPUTERNAME = UGSERVER
APP_POOL_ID = Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 2
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
ClusterLog = C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\cluster.log
SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 15
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 0401
lib = C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\
BPADir = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\
VS90COMNTOOLS = d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
OS = Windows_NT

Request Details
Url=http://ugserver:8080/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx [method = POST]
User Agent=Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 9.0.21022.8)
Headers=Content-Length=354&Content-Type=text%2fxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2cgzip%2cgzip&Accept-Language=en-US&Authorization=NTLM+TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAAAAAAEgAAAAAAAAASAAAAAAAAABIAAAAAAAAAEgAAAAAAAAASAAAAAAAAABIAAAANcKI4gUCzg4AAAAP&Expect=100-continue&Host=ugserver%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+9.0.21022.8)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=8d9f4a30-16f3-4fc6-8daa-3aaefd2a8ea6&SOAPAction=%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2005%2f06%2fServices%2fServerStatus%2f03%2fCheckAuthentication%22
Path=/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx
Local Request=True
User Host Address=192.168.1.186
User=UGSERVER\Administrator [auth = NTLM]

Application Provided Information
Team Foundation Application Information
Event Log Source = TFS Services
Configured Team Foundation Server = http://UGSERVER:8080
License Type = EnterpriseLicense
Server Culture = en-US
Activity Logging Name = Integration
Component Name = CS
Initialized = No
Requests Processed = 0


Exception: SqlException
Message: Cannot open database "TfsIntegration" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.
SQL Exception Class: 11
SQL Exception Number: 4060
SQL Exception Server: UGSERVER\UGSERVER
SQL Exception Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
SQL Exception State: 1
SQL Exception Procedure:
SQL Exception Line Number: 65536
SQL Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.
    Class: 14
    Number: 18456
    Server: UGSERVER\UGSERVER
    Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
    State: 1
    Procedure:
    Line Number: 65536
Exception Data Dictionary follows
HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
HelpLink.EvtID = 4060
HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
HelpLink.LinkId = 20476
Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.RegistrationDataAccessor.GetRegisteredTools(String toolId, String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.RegistrationDataAccessor.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId, String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.RegistrationEventSchemaProvider..ctor(String applicationPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.CombinationEventSchemaProvider..ctor(String applicationPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Global.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.TeamFoundationApplication.Init()

Application Domain Information
Assembly Name=mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
InternalName:     mscorlib.dll
OriginalFilename: mscorlib.dll
FileVersion:      2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
FileDescription:  Microsoft Common Language Runtime Class Library
Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)

Assembly Name=System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll
InternalName:     System.Web.dll
OriginalFilename: System.Web.dll
FileVersion:      2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
FileDescription:  System.Web.dll
Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)

Assembly Name=System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
InternalName:     System.dll
OriginalFilename: System.dll
FileVersion:      2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
FileDescription:  .NET Framework
Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)

Assembly Name=System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
InternalName:     System.Xml.dll
OriginalFilename: System.Xml.dll
FileVersion:      2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
FileDescription:  .NET Framework
Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)

Assembly Name=System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
InternalName:     System.Configuration.dll
OriginalFilename: System.Configuration.dll
FileVersion:      2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
FileDescription:  System.Configuration.dll
Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)

Assembly Name=System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
InternalName:     System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
OriginalFilename: System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
FileVersion:      2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
FileDescription:  System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)

Assembly Name=Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=8.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll
InternalName:     Microsoft.JScript.dll
OriginalFilename: Microsoft.JScript.dll
FileVersion:      8.0.50727.1433
FileDescription:  Microsoft.JScript.dll
Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2005
ProductVersion:   8.0.50727.1433
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         Language Neutral

Assembly Name=CppCodeProvider, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=8.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CppCodeProvider\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CppCodeProvider.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CppCodeProvider\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CppCodeProvider.dll
InternalName:     CppCodeProvider.dll
OriginalFilename: CppCodeProvider.dll
FileVersion:      8.0.50727.813
FileDescription:  CppCodeProvider.dll
Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2005
ProductVersion:   8.0.50727.813
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         Language Neutral

Assembly Name=App_global.asax.3iyvjmrk, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=0.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\a8a490c5\21badae0\App_global.asax.3iyvjmrk.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\a8a490c5\21badae0\App_global.asax.3iyvjmrk.dll
InternalName:     App_global.asax.3iyvjmrk.dll
OriginalFilename: App_global.asax.3iyvjmrk.dll
FileVersion:      0.0.0.0
FileDescription:  
Product:         
ProductVersion:   0.0.0.0
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         Language Neutral

Assembly Name=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=9.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\a8a490c5\21badae0\assembly\dl3\c371c214\00f59c0d_7422c801\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.DLL
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\a8a490c5\21badae0\assembly\dl3\c371c214\00f59c0d_7422c801\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.DLL
InternalName:     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll
OriginalFilename: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll
FileVersion:      9.0.21022.8
FileDescription:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll
Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2008
ProductVersion:   9.0.21022.8
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         Language Neutral

Assembly Name=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
Assembly Version=9.0.0.0
Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Assembly File Version:
File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
InternalName:     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
OriginalFilename: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
FileVersion:      9.0.21022.8
FileDescription:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Product:

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

If you check the above details then you would have seen the following:

```
Exception: SqlException
    Message: Cannot open database "TfsIntegration" requested by the login. The login failed.
    Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.
```

The database server has got the user. Then, why?

I tried to repair it from Add/Remove and got the following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server Setup
---------------------------
Error 29002.The Team Foundation databases could not be repaired. For more information, see the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) log.
---------------------------
Retry   Cancel  
---------------------------

**I checked the event viewer it has:**

Event Type:    Error
Event Source:    MsiInstaller
Event Category:    None
Event ID:    10005
Date:        2/2/2010
Time:        10:21:57 AM
User:        UGSERVER\Administrator
Computer:    UGSERVER
Description:
Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server - ENU -- Error 29002.The Team Foundation databases could not be repaired. For more information, see the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) log.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 7b 33 35 45 44 37 38 38   {35ED788
0008: 42 2d 44 41 36 42 2d 33   B-DA6B-3
0010: 33 37 33 2d 42 42 32 42   373-BB2B
0018: 2d 41 36 38 43 31 34 39   -A68C149
0020: 45 41 38 31 41 7d         EA81A}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Exception: SqlException 
    Message: Cannot open database "TfsIntegration" requested by the login. The login failed. 
    Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.`

This sounds like the root of the problem. Check that's nothing changed on your network, and that nobody has gone in to meddle with the database permissions. Also check that Windows authentication is still enabled (not SQL Server).

Comment: @Jeremy nothing changed, I believe. The database has LOCAL SERVICE user then why it saying this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, TFS does not run as NT AUTHORITY/LOCAL USER, rather as \TFSSERVICE.